# Maven Resources Src vs Target Directory

Tags: maven, encoding, resources

I'm reading a private key file and when I read it from the target directory I get an exception:

> Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not
>   properly padded

If I read it from the src directory it works fine.

Is this an encoding problem? How do I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Almost 100% of the people who try to read a **file** from the scr/main/resource-directory or target/classes-directory do actually want to have its content read from the classpath.
So instead I would suggest to use Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/resource") (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).
The plugin responsible for moving these resource file to the target directory is the [maven-resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html). 
By default it will use the encoding of your system and [Maven will warn for that](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning). This entry also explains how to set it properly.